# IE CSS border missing when using display:none

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer (I've tested in all v6 - v9) the border on the sub-menu does not at first appear when you hover over the text. The second time you hover it will display. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome - i.e. it always displays the border. I've put an example page up on [my site](http://ianchanning.com/ie-border-bug/).

IE (on hover):

[image: IE]

FF/Chrome (on hover):

[image: FF]

There's nothing fancy here, some css, onmouseover/onmouseout Javascript to set style.display = block/none. I've followed some of the ideas in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586481/327074) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586420/problem-with-css-hover-drop-down-menu-in-internet-explorer).

I've stripped it down to the minimum to try and find the problem, but still no luck.

The sub-menu ul element has display:none set on it. It seems that IE doesn't bother drawing the border until it has display:block set, and doesn't draw it initially when Javascript is used to display the element.

```
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ul, li                      {padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}
    ul#hover_menu_list, 
    ul#hover_menu_list ul       {list-style-type:none;}
    ul#hover_menu_list li       {float:left;position:relative;display:inline;}
    ul#hover_menu_list li ul    {border:1px solid #000;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:20px;width:170px;}
    ul#hover_menu_list li ul li {display:block; clear:left; float:left;width:140px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="hover_menu_list" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menu1').style.display='none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menu1').style.display='block';">
        <li>
            Menu
            <ul id="menu1">
                <li>Submenu1</li>
                <li>Submenu2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: The problem was indeed a doctype issue. Adding in either a transitional or strict doctype fixes the problem. The linked page has been updated with the fix.

Comment: It seems to work fine on IE6-IE9 in my testing see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/FpCEW/

I would recommend checking your doctype to make sure it's a w3c compliant doctype.

Comment: It does work in jsfiddle - but I suspect they are doing something to fix it. If you look at the example page http://ianchanning.com/ie-border-bug/ in IE you should see the bug. There's no DOCTYPE set.

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle does very much to "fix" your code. That's kind of the point...

Comment: it's the missing doctype, indeed. but I'm also wondering why you are using JS, and not just make use of the :hover pseudo class: http://jsfiddle.net/XCXhE/

Comment: @ptriek that won't work on touchscreens...

Comment: This works locally in IE9 but not on the web. Please add a doctype to the web source. All new web pages are required to have one. Use strict, never transitional.

Comment: But why? Why would IE's quirks mode decide to not show the border the first time only? What would cause that? I mean I could live with not showing the border at all, or not showing anything. But this makes me curious!

Comment: @Rob The difference between a doctype and no doctype is not the same as strict and transitional mode. You mean standards and quirks mode. Or in Microsoftspeak, compliance and compatibility mode.

Comment: @MrLister - I said he should use a strict doctype and not transitional because new web pages have no use for transitional.

Comment: @MrLister - Haven't looked yet but quirks mode does not follow the box model properly and I'm assuming it's covering up or misplacing the borders.

Comment: It was indeed the doctype. I've removed the doctype from the code above, to show the original problem. Adding in this `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` fixed the problem

Comment: @ptriek the reason I'm using JS is purely because I'm fixing someone else's code. This is all much better done by superfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it looks like you are missing a doctype.

Oldie but goodie:

> http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't seem like adding a doctype helped

Comment: @icc97 - In the comments I mentioned it works locally, but my local copy had a doctype. Removing the doctype makes it fail just like online...which doesn't have a doctype. Mathletics is correct and, perhaps, it didn't work for you due to cache and you need to try again with a refresh.

Comment: @icc97 Rob is right; your page isn't showing up with a doctype yet. Check the source!

Comment: indeed, correct, I got mixed up between my local copy and the online version

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in the comments to the original question, the example on your page that you link definitely doesn't have a doctype listed at all in the code.  I'd recommend adding a doctype, and it should correct your issue.

I've created your example on jsfiddle here and tested it on IE6-IE9, and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/FpCEW

They include a valid doctype with all of their pages, and it appears work fine.

That said, you can use the pseudo `:hover` item in the css, however `:hover` doesn't work consistently in the older versions of IE, so that may not be an option without adding some additional code to add in support for it (maybe modernizer supports this).